# Why does adding float:left/right to my CSS moves another div to the top?

Tags: html, css

Desired behavior: the center image of the restaurant to be centered horizontally, with a `margin-top` of 100px.

Specific problem: When I add the `float` property to the left and right images (the arrow and the magnifying glass), the center image moves all the way to the top of its container.

Reproducer: Here is a link to my CodePen: https://codepen.io/annabaker/pen/gObmWWx

HTML:

```
<div class="restaurant-widget">
    <div class="left-arrow">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/8T03wEO.png">
    </div>
    <div class="search">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/zQX1b7N/zoom-32.png">
    </div>
    <div class="restaurant">
       <img src="https://i.imgur.com/4FeEerb.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="header">
        THE WATER CLUB
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.restaurant-widget {
    color: #4c4c4c;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 16px rgba(0,0,0,.58);
    border-radius:1px;
    /* this centers the actual widget itself, provided width is defined */
    margin: auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 900px;
}

.left-arrow img {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    float: left;
 }

.search img {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    float: right;
 }

.restaurant img {
    /* this makesthe restaurant image circular */
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid grey;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 16px rgba(0,0,0,.58);
    display: block;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's due to "collapsing margins" (you can google that for details...): The top margin of `.restaurant img` is "merged" with the margin of `.restaurant-widget`, resulting in a margin *outside*  of the container.

To avoid that, you can add `padding-top: 1px` to the container (`.restaurant-widget`)

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you use `float`, you remove the element from its normal flow in the page and put it in another **context**. You can imagine the floating element really "floating" above the elements in the basic context. As all HTML in a page is rendered line by line, the elements were been created everyone in its context (based on its `display` properties).

The positioning of you central image when the others are not floated occurs the way it occurs because of the fact that the other images *are in the same context* as the central image, and so central image occupy that spot. When you do apply `float`, you *remove* the other images from its context, so central image can now occupy a new spot on the page. About this topic of contexts, I recommend you a further reading here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context

There are some ways to achieve what you want. *CSS Flexbox* and *CSS Grid* are, probably, the best and the simpler ways. I redid your code using CSS Grid, here's a Codepen: https://codepen.io/alac1984/pen/WNbpYmb